# Need explanation of "jta-data-source"

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jta

I have the following line in a persistence.xml. Can someone explain *how* this tells hibernate how to connect to the relevant datasource?

Let's say that I ran a local mysql server, is this where I'd define that source as "something:localhost:something"? How would I adapt this line to add that data source instead?

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/test</jta-data-source>
```

Answer (score 1):

Java EE application servers (like JBoss, WebLogic, WebSphere, etc.) provide transaction support through JTA. They also allow defining data sources that are enrolled in JTA transactions. These data sources are made available to applications deployed in the application server using the JNDI api: the datasource has a JNDI name, and the application uses JNDI to retrieve the datasource registered under that name. This JNDI name is what is inside the above `jta-data-source` element.

Using this configuration thus means that JPA will use this JNDI name to get the datasource configured in the application server.

Comment: Right, so jta is only useful when running the program on a web server. If I'm running a class without an application server, such as when doing a unit test, what would I need to do, to get a persistence provider for use with the EntityManagerFactory? Let's assume I'd connect to an already existing sql server.

Comment: Here's an example and explanation I found by googling for... persistence.xml: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/persistence-unit. Here's another explanation anc reference I found by googling for "hibernate persistence.xml": http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html